# how to set a function's value in array in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am working in wordpress and using buddypress theme. In my php file i want to set value of a buddy press functions into an array parameter like following

```
PLUGIN_METHOD( array( 'Para1' => 'Value1', 'Para2' => bp_activity_user_link()));
```

But i am unable to set value of function's into array.

Please suggest me right way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function echos the result and returns void, so it won't get passed to the array.  Use this function:

`bp_get_activity_user_link();`

---

Ok, last try :).  It's possible your version of BP doesn't have that function.  You can try this:

```
ob_start();
bp_activity_user_link();
$link_out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
PLUGIN_METHOD( array( 'Para1' => 'Value1', 'Para2' => $link_out));
```

Comment: That's such a nice answer

Comment: Ok. I am agree with your words. but your suggested function is not working for me.

Comment: Check my edit, hopefully this helps. If that doesn't work, var_dump($link_out) and tell us the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
PLUGIN_METHOD( array( 'Para1' => 'Value1', 'Para2' => bp_activity_user_link(); ) );
                                                                             ^
```

You just have to fix the parse error by removing your `;` after the nested function call and that's it

```
PLUGIN_METHOD( array( 'Para1' => 'Value1', 'Para2' => bp_activity_user_link()));
```

Comment: There is no way under the sun it won't work. Now whether the function `PLUGIN_METHOD()` works as you expect or not is another problem. But that's the way you sent a function's returned value in an array to another function.

Comment: Ok. if i hard code the second parameter then it works well. not working with above code.